# Make custom type non-broadcastable

Tags: julia

Say I have

```
struct Foo
    x::Int
end
bar(f::Foo, val::Int) = f.x + val
```

I want to broadcast against this singular object

```
foo = Foo(1)
z = bar.(foo, collect(1:10))
```

but I get `MethodError: no method matching length(::Foo)`.

How can I declare that `Foo` isn't broadcastable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shortcut the broadcasting by returning itself with

```
import Base.Broadcast.broadcastable
broadcastable(f::Foo) = Ref(f)
```

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.Broadcast.broadcastable